# LINQ Performance Optimization

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-objects

I have the following LINQ query that I want to optimize. Our system is heavily dependent on this, so even slight optimization will help over all. Any ideas are welcome, not sure where to even start..

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using System.Linq;

  namespace Test
  {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                JoinTestClass testClass = new JoinTestClass();
                testClass.GenerateRandomObjects();
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            stopwatch.Start();
            var totalMatched = testClass.ComputeMatches();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Total time for attempt {i} : {stopwatch.Elapsed}, total Matched: {totalMatched}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}

public class JoinTestClass
{
    List<ProductPurchase> ListOne = new List<ProductPurchase>();
    List<ProductPurchase> ListTwo = new List<ProductPurchase>();

    public void GenerateRandomObjects()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
        {
            ListOne.Add(new ProductPurchase
            {
                ProductID = new Random().Next(1, 300000),
                Price = new Random().Next(1, 100),
                Quantity = new Random().Next(1, 30),
                GlobalQuantity = new Random().Next(1, 5000)
            });

            ListTwo.Add(new ProductPurchase
            {
                ProductID = new Random().Next(1, 300000),
                Price = new Random().Next(1, 100),
                Quantity = new Random().Next(1, 30),
                GlobalQuantity = new Random().Next(1, 10000)
            });
        }
    }

    public int ComputeMatches()
    {
        var matched = (from listOne in ListOne
                       join listTwo in ListTwo on listOne.ProductID equals listTwo.ProductID into matches
                       select new
                       {
                           ProductID = listOne.ProductID,
                           ROQ = listOne.Price,
                           RUQ = listOne.Quantity,
                           RPQ = listOne.GlobalQuantity,
                           RV = listOne.Price * listOne.Quantity * listOne.GlobalQuantity,
                           BMPProduct = matches.OrderBy(m => m.Price).FirstOrDefault(),
                           WAP = (matches.IsEmpty() || matches.Sum(m => m.Quantity * m.GlobalQuantity) == 0) ? 0 : matches.Sum(m => m.Quantity * m.GlobalQuantity * m.Price) / matches.Sum(m => m.Quantity * m.GlobalQuantity)
                       })
                     .ToList();

        return matched.Where(m => m.WAP != 0).Count();
    }


}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return !source.Any();
    }
}

public class ProductPurchase
{
    public int ProductID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public decimal Price
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int Quantity
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int GlobalQuantity
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

}

Output:

> Total time for attempt 0 : 00:00:01.3402090, total Matched: 405194
>
> Total time for attempt 1 : 00:00:01.4374070, total Matched: 405807
>
> Total time for attempt 2 : 00:00:01.4081370, total Matched: 405206

**EDIT:**
I have edited the post to add the full code of the test namespace and results on my machine.

P.S. I can NOT bring in any sort of concurrency in here for optimization purposes as other parts of the system call this ComputeMatches function in Parallel, and as I have learned the hard way.. nesting concurrencies does the opposite of optimizations.

Comment: Is this Linq to objects or to SQL?

Comment: You're calculating `matches.Sum(m => m.SomeProperty5 * m.SomeProperty6)` over and over again, you should do it once and cache the result

Comment: @tymtam linq to objects. (List<SomeObject>)

Comment: @JohanP wouldn't the SomeProperty5 and SomeProerty6 be different per each iteration?

Comment: @Gio Indeed, but they wouldn't be different for the same iteration - this is the problem that JohanP is highlighting. For a single iteration, you are repeating the calculation.

Comment: Oh I think you are talking about the double .Sum within the operation of Prop8? Yeah, I think that makes sense. But for me to cache that I would have to convert this to a loop I believe, unless I can perhaps use lambda function within select statement? But thats probably not that performant @John

Comment: @Gio You could probably do a double select. The first select would save a cached value, and the second select would use it.

Comment: @Gio In my answer, I remove the `ToList` - is that "cheating" (in the context of your question)? Or acceptable?

Comment: May be just don't use LINQ here?

Answer (score 1):

These changes reduce execution time from about 0.8 seconds per iteration to about 0.61 seconds per iteration (on my Windows laptop, running .NET Core 2.1).

*Both of those times are factoring in the reduced time due to my explicit `GC` calls:*

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    // Add in the next three lines, to ensure that the majority of GC is occurring _before_ the stopwatch starts measuring
    GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
```

The below changes are largely the introduction of the `ToLookup`, the removal of one of the `ToList` calls, and the calculation of `sum` only a single time:

```
public int ComputeMatches()
{
    var dicTwo = ListTwo.ToLookup(z => z.ProductID);

    var matched = (from listOne in ListOne
                   let matches = dicTwo[listOne.ProductID]
                   let sum = matches.Sum(m => m.Quantity * m.GlobalQuantity)
                   select new
                   {
                       ProductID = listOne.ProductID,
                       ROQ = listOne.Price,
                       RUQ = listOne.Quantity,
                       RPQ = listOne.GlobalQuantity,
                       RV = listOne.Price * listOne.Quantity * listOne.GlobalQuantity,
                       BMPProduct = matches.OrderBy(m => m.Price).FirstOrDefault(),
                       WAP = sum == 0 ? 0 : matches.Sum(m => m.Quantity * m.GlobalQuantity * m.Price) / sum
                   });

    return matched.Where(m => m.WAP != 0).Count();
}
```

*Note that the introduction of the `ToLookup` may have wider system impacts (e.g. more memory usage, more frequent GC) so you should do further real testing before using this).*

If you are willing to use [`MoreLinq`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) then you can get it down to around 0.56 seconds (for the second iteration onwards - the first will be slower);

```
BMPProduct = matches.MinBy(m => m.Price),
```

Comment: @AntonínLejsek That is a fair point. Let me make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

There is one of the single most common wasting - sorting the whole sequence just to get the biggest item. In linq2sql this sin would be optimized away, but in linq2objects it is hardly the case. You should definitely get used to have some MaxBy in your tool set and use it every time you need the biggest item.

Just as a side note, you use Random in a wrong way. You should not create new instance of this class for every random number. Just create one instance and keep pulling numbers from that.

You should also avoid multiple calculation of the same thing multiple times. I would not even call this an optimalization. It is just writing code that does not waste, you should do it by habit most of the time I think.

If you need maximum speed, you have to sacrifice everything else. Throw out abstration layers, unroll everything, cut corners. If it is really needed for that 1% of the time critical code, it can be done, but it would not be pretty. It should definitely not be done frequently. You have been warned.

I implemented two ways to do that join. The first one uses hash dictionary to do that. It removes repeating of calculations and produces less iterators, as it calculates all subsums in one go. Note that .GroupBy.ToDictionary is roughly equal to .ToLookup, but Dictionary provides TryGetValue while lookup always return empty sequence. The second approach uses merge join. It sorts both sequences and merges them. You can conveniently fuse the merging and subsum calculation. It turns out this is the fastest approach I found here. And if you could get the sequences already sorted, it would be even faster.

I made slight change, the function returns list of named class instances, not anonymous, so I can verify the results. For mjwills code I had to add ToList, which mostly eliminated the speedup he provided. And the results are here

```
JoinTestClassOrig avg[ms]: 1161 / rounds[ms]: 1158, 1160, 1158, 1170
JoinTestClassHash_mjwills avg[ms]: 1158 / rounds[ms]: 1169, 1152, 1162, 1151
JoinTestClassHashMe avg[ms]: 857 / rounds[ms]: 865, 841, 840, 883
JoinTestClassMergeMe avg[ms]: 633 / rounds[ms]: 632, 631, 634, 636
```

and the code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testCases = new List<TestClass>()
        {
            new JoinTestClassOrig(),
            new JoinTestClassHash_mjwills(),
            new JoinTestClassHashMe(),
            new JoinTestClassMergeMe(),
        };
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        List<List<ProductPurchaseOutp>> results = new List<List<ProductPurchaseOutp>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            foreach (var testClass in testCases)
            {
                testClass.GenerateRandomObjects(1);
                GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();

                stopwatch.Restart();
                var res = (testClass.ComputeMatches());
                stopwatch.Stop();

                if (i > 0)
                {
                    results.Add(res);
                    testClass.results.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Checking results...");


        int cnt = results
            .Select(r => r
                .OrderBy(o => o.ProductID)
                .ThenBy(o => o.ROQ)
                .ThenBy(o => o.RPQ)
                .ThenBy(o => o.RUQ)
                .ThenBy(o => o.RV)
                .ToList()
            )
            .Aggregate((a, b) =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (!a[i].IsEqualTo(b[i])) { throw new Exception("Sequences are not equal"); }
            }
            return a;
        }).Where(m => m.WAP != 0).Count();


        Console.WriteLine("Count: " + cnt.ToString());

        foreach (var test in testCases)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(test.name() + " avg[ms]: " + (int)test.results.Average() + " / rounds[ms]: " + string.Join(", ", test.results));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}

public abstract class TestClass
{
    protected List<ProductPurchase> ListOne = new List<ProductPurchase>();
    protected List<ProductPurchase> ListTwo = new List<ProductPurchase>();

    public List<long> results = new List<long>();

    public void GenerateRandomObjects(int seed)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random(seed);

        ListOne.Clear();
        ListTwo.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
        {
            ListOne.Add(new ProductPurchase
            {
                ProductID = rnd.Next(1, 300000),
                Price = rnd.Next(1, 100),
                Quantity = rnd.Next(1, 30),
                GlobalQuantity = rnd.Next(1, 5000)
            });

            ListTwo.Add(new ProductPurchase
            {
                ProductID = rnd.Next(1, 300000),
                Price = rnd.Next(1, 100),
                Quantity = rnd.Next(1, 30),
                GlobalQuantity = rnd.Next(1, 10000)
            });
        }
    }

    public abstract List<ProductPurchaseOutp> ComputeMatches();

    public string name()
    {
        return this.GetType().Name;
    }
}

public class JoinTestClassOrig : TestClass
{
    public override List<ProductPurchaseOutp> ComputeMatches()
    {
        var matched = (from listOne in ListOne
                       join listTwo in ListTwo on listOne.ProductID equals listTwo.ProductID into matches
                       select new ProductPurchaseOutp
                       {
                           ProductID = listOne.ProductID,
                           ROQ = listOne.Price,
                           RUQ = listOne.Quantity,
                           RPQ = listOne.GlobalQuantity,
                           RV = listOne.Price * listOne.Quantity * listOne.GlobalQuantity,
                           BMPProduct = matches.OrderBy(m => m.Price).FirstOrDefault(),
                           WAP = (matches.IsEmpty() || matches.Sum(m => m.Quantity * m.GlobalQuantity) == 0) ? 0 : matches.Sum(m => m.Quantity * m.GlobalQuantity * m.Price) / matches.Sum(m => m.Quantity * m.GlobalQuantity)
                       })
                     .ToList();

        return matched;
    }
}

public class JoinTestClassHash_mjwills : TestClass
{
    public override List<ProductPurchaseOutp> ComputeMatches()
    {
        var dicTwo = ListTwo.ToLookup(z => z.ProductID);

        var matched = (from listOne in ListOne
                       let matches = dicTwo[listOne.ProductID]
                       let sum = matches.Sum(m => m.Quantity * m.GlobalQuantity)
                       select new ProductPurchaseOutp
                       {
                           ProductID = listOne.ProductID,
                           ROQ = listOne.Price,
                           RUQ = listOne.Quantity,
                           RPQ = listOne.GlobalQuantity,
                           RV = listOne.Price * listOne.Quantity * listOne.GlobalQuantity,
                           BMPProduct = matches.OrderBy(m => m.Price).FirstOrDefault(),
                           WAP = sum == 0 ? 0 : matches.Sum(m => m.Quantity * m.GlobalQuantity * m.Price) / sum
                       });

        return matched.ToList();
    }
}

public class JoinTestClassMergeMe : TestClass
{
    private IEnumerable<ProductPurchaseOutp> matched()
    {
        var l1 = ListOne
            .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID);

        var l2 = ListTwo
            .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID);

        bool eo2 = false;

        using (var en1 = l1.GetEnumerator())
        using (var en2 = l2.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!en1.MoveNext()) { yield break; }
            var cur1 = en1.Current;
            ProductPurchase cur2 = null;
            if (en2.MoveNext())
            {
                cur2 = en2.Current;
            }
            else
            {
                eo2 = true;
            }


            do
            {
                int ID = cur1.ProductID;

                long qsum = 0;
                decimal psum = 0;
                decimal min = decimal.MaxValue;
                decimal wap = 0;
                ProductPurchase minp = null;
                while (!eo2 && cur2.ProductID <= ID)
                {
                    if (cur2.ProductID == ID)
                    {
                        long quantity = (long)cur2.Quantity * cur2.GlobalQuantity;
                        var price = cur2.Price;
                        qsum += quantity;
                        psum += quantity * price;
                        if (price < min)
                        {
                            minp = cur2;
                            min = price;
                        }
                    }
                    if (en2.MoveNext())
                    {
                        cur2 = en2.Current;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        eo2 = true;
                    }
                };

                if (qsum != 0)
                {
                    wap = psum / qsum;
                }

                do
                {
                    yield return new ProductPurchaseOutp()
                    {
                        ProductID = cur1.ProductID,
                        ROQ = cur1.Price,
                        RUQ = cur1.Quantity,
                        RPQ = cur1.GlobalQuantity,
                        RV = cur1.Price * cur1.Quantity * cur1.GlobalQuantity,
                        BMPProduct = minp,
                        WAP = wap
                    };
                } while (en1.MoveNext() && (cur1 = en1.Current).ProductID == ID);

                if (cur1.ProductID == ID) { yield break; }

            } while (true);
        }
    }

    public override List<ProductPurchaseOutp> ComputeMatches()
    {
        return matched().ToList();
    }
}

public class JoinTestClassHashMe : TestClass
{
    public override List<ProductPurchaseOutp> ComputeMatches()
    {
        var l2 = ListTwo
            .GroupBy(l => l.ProductID)
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Key);

        return ListOne
            .Select(listOne =>
        {
            decimal wap = 0;
            ProductPurchase minp = null;

            if (l2.TryGetValue(listOne.ProductID, out var matches))
            {
                long qsum = 0;
                decimal psum = 0;
                decimal min = decimal.MaxValue;
                foreach (var m in matches)
                {
                    long quantity = (long)m.Quantity * m.GlobalQuantity;
                    var price = m.Price;
                    qsum += quantity;
                    psum += quantity * price;
                    if (price < min)
                    {
                        minp = m;
                        min = price;
                    }
                }

                if (qsum != 0)
                {
                    wap = psum / qsum;
                }
            }


            return new ProductPurchaseOutp
            {
                ProductID = listOne.ProductID,
                ROQ = listOne.Price,
                RUQ = listOne.Quantity,
                RPQ = listOne.GlobalQuantity,
                RV = listOne.Price * listOne.Quantity * listOne.GlobalQuantity,
                BMPProduct = minp,
                WAP = wap
            };

        })
        .ToList();
    }
}






public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return !source.Any();
    }
}


public class ProductPurchase
{
    public int ProductID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public decimal Price
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int Quantity
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int GlobalQuantity
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class ProductPurchaseOutp
{
    public int ProductID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public decimal ROQ
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int RUQ
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int RPQ
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public decimal RV
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ProductPurchase BMPProduct { get; set; }
    public decimal WAP { get; set; }

    public bool IsEqualTo(ProductPurchaseOutp b)
    {
        return this.ProductID == b.ProductID
            && this.ROQ == b.ROQ
            && this.RPQ == b.RPQ
            && this.RUQ == b.RUQ
            && this.RV == b.RV
            && this.WAP == b.WAP
            && (this.BMPProduct == null && b.BMPProduct == null ||
               this.BMPProduct != null && b.BMPProduct != null
            && this.BMPProduct.GlobalQuantity == b.BMPProduct.GlobalQuantity
            && this.BMPProduct.Price == b.BMPProduct.Price
            && this.BMPProduct.ProductID == b.BMPProduct.ProductID
            && this.BMPProduct.Quantity == b.BMPProduct.Quantity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. `join l2 in listTwo on l1.SomeID equals listTwo.SomeID into matches`

doesn't compile. `listTwo.SomeID` should be `l2.SomeID` shouldn't it?

2. What is `IsEmpty`?
3. You never seem to use `l2` but the join makes an impact on the results (you couldn't just do it on `listOne`). This is hard to understand.
4. The calculated values `6`,`7` and `8` are actually hard to understand as they are calculated as the list builds itself. Operations like this are very vulnerable to multi-threading issues.

I'd say that in the current form the code would be unmaintainable for a dev like me and will be a source of hard to reproduce bugs.

Comment: Great questions! I apologize for not giving enough information in the first place. Please see my editions.

Comment: @tymtam this should be a comment to the question, not an answer